# convert one to many join response to object in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have 3 tables in MySql which are joined using one to many relations. In node js, I got multiple rows now to convert them into a single object containing these data.

Ex. 1. User table which has user details
2. cards table (credit card or debit card user has)
3. Transaction table (transaction done with the cards)

I have a POJO which looks like this:

```
user:{
  "firstname":"sandy",
   ...
  "cards":[        //this is a array of cards
      {"card_no":"12321",
      ...
      "transactions":[       //this is list of transactions

       ]}

  ]
}
```

From my MySQL query I got all these as multiple rows, now I have to convert them into POJO. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: For now, I am hitting multiple queries from my nodejs to construct the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an ORM such as Sequelize is the best way to answer your need